# set int from sql query

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to set an int value from an sql query. In my ios app I can assign an int value to a photo ID, store it and retrieve it fine. The problem comes if I want to overwrite the photo with a new jpg but still using the existing IdPhoto and therefore the same filename, e.g. 1.jpg. I first check whether the user exists. If so I update the photo (this is where I need to set the IdPhoto) otherwise I create a photo with a new ID (works fine).

```
function uploadDetails($Name, $Location, $photoData, $IdPhoto) {

    $uploads = query("SELECT Name, IdPhoto FROM users WHERE Name = '%s'  limit 1",$Name);


    if (count($uploads['result'])>0) {

        $result = query("UPDATE users SET Name='$Name', Location='$Location', IdPhoto='$IdPhoto' WHERE Name = '%s'", $Name);

    //Need to define IdPhoto from users table

        if (move_uploaded_file($photoData['tmp_name'], "icons/".$IdPhoto.".jpg")) {

            thumb("icons/".$IdPhoto.".jpg", 180);

                    //I can print out confirmation to the iPhone app
                    print json_encode(array('$IdPhoto'=>$IdPhoto));
         } else {
                    //print out an error message to the iPhone app
                    errorJson('Upload on server problem');
        };

    }
    else {
        if ($photoData['error']==0) {

         $result = query("INSERT INTO users(Name, Location) VALUES('%s','%s')", $Name, $Location);


            if (!$result['error']) {

                // fetch the active connection to the database (it's initialized automatically in lib.php)
                global $link;

                // get the last automatically generated ID in the table
                $IdPhoto = mysqli_insert_id($link);

                if (move_uploaded_file($photoData['tmp_name'], "icons/".$IdPhoto.".jpg")) {

                    thumb("icons/".$IdPhoto.".jpg", 180);

                    print json_encode(array('successful'=>1));
                } else {

                    errorJson('Upload on server problem');
                };

            } else {
                errorJson('Upload database problem.'.$result['error']);
            }

         }
    }
}
```

So the problem lies in the first part of the code where I need to update the photo but still use the same IdPhoto

---

**EDIT**

The piece of code I needed was as follows:

```
$getID = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link, "SELECT IdPhoto FROM users WHERE Name = '$Name'"));
$IdPhoto = $getID['IdPhoto'];
```

Although I got to the answer eventually myself, I appreciate feedback of how to phrase questions better in future. And writing out the full code probably helped me look at the bigger picture and see where I was going wrong.

Comment: *"So far I have"* - which is what we call pseudo-code.

Comment: I don't understand how people are supposed to learn if people just downvote and don't explain why!

Comment: you have to fetch results from your sql statement

Comment: learn? we're not a school. Plus, if it's of any comfort, I didn't downvote. Voted to close as unclear, but not dv.

Comment: Thank you @xNeyte. Could you point me to an example?

Comment: how many rows is your query returning?

Comment: What database are you using - MySQL? What library are you using - PDO/mysql, mysqli, mysql? It is hard to answer without this information (and may be why people downvoted - not possible to answer in its current form). Also, please switch to parameter binding if you can - the `%s` may be vulnerable to injection.

Comment: @JeremyC. there is only one result. I can print the result of my query in my ios app and it is returning the correct $IdPhoto. but I can't figure out how to assign the photo with it.

Comment: that ^ should have been in your question right away. You probably got downvoted because of lack of information and what you want to achieve. Along with any other information that could make your question clearer.

Comment: try $IdPhoto = $result['IdPhoto'] // if that doesn't work try: $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); after that you do $IdPhoto = $row['IdPhoto']; Unless you are not using mysql_query in which case I can't help because I never used mysqli or pdo :p

Comment: thank you @Fred-ii- I appreciate feedback so that I can ask questions in a more informative way. It's hard for people to learn if others simply downvote and leave no explanation or constructive criticism in the comments.

Comment: You're welcome. Now, since we're working with files, how are they being populated from, a form? usually is. Files require a POST method and a valid enctype in order to be processed properly. `$result = query` we don't know which MySQL API you're using to connect with. `mysql_`, `mysqli_`, PDO? Very hard to help out when there's a lot of important and relevant information missing.

Comment: I'm using mysqli. I can generate a new IdPhoto  with  $IdPhoto = mysqli_insert_id($link); it's when i come to reusing an existing IdPhoto, i.e. there is already a photo named 1.jpg but I want to update that file with a new photo called 1.jpg.

Comment: I think it might be something like $result->fetch_row()[1] , to get your IdPhoto from your result

Comment: Please place all your relevant comments in your question. People won't go through all the comments to see what you're trying to achieve. That is what I think is the reason why you received so many downvotes. Mention everything; the API, what you're trying to achieve and what you tried. all from your comments also.

Comment: Retracted close vote, much better.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is extremely vague but I'm going to take the following assumptions:

1. Your query will only ever return a single record
2. You are using MySQLi

Once you have run the query and stored the results into $result you can use the following code to get the IdPhoto:

```
//Store a row from results into variable
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

//Store IdPhoto into variable
$IdPhoto = $row['IdPhoto'];
```

Note: Also you are selecting Name from the database when you already have the Name since you're using it to fetch the record

Comment: Sorry I am using mysqli

Comment: I will amend my answer